# Why are my links' positions drastically altered when I remove an image?

Tags: html, css, position, css-position

I have six links lined up horizontally below my header logo with an image underneath them. I positioned these links using the relative property and would like them to work as a menu bar and want them applied to all of my pages for ideal navigation. So I simply copied and pasted the links into my other pages HTML code.

Well, on my other pages I don't necessarily want an image directly underneath my links, but when I remove it my links' positions are drastically altered. Here is a GIF of my website and my problem:

[image]

Here is the body of my "About" page:

```css
#about {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 315px;
  left: -112px;
}

#news {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 315px;
  left: -67px;
}

#store {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 315px;
  left: -22px
}

#music {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 315px;
  right: -22px
}

#connect {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 315px;
  right: -67px
}

#submit {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 315px;
  right: -112px
}
```

```html
<body>
  <hr id="line1">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <a href="gbwebsite.html"><img id="gblogo" src="images/GB.png" alt="good boy logo" width="128" height="128"></a>
  </div>

  <div id="font" class="wrapper">
    <a id="about" href="about.html" class="stroke">
      <font>ABOUT</a>
    </font>
    <a id="news" href="news.html" class="stroke">
      <font>NEWS</a>
    </font>
    <a id="store" href="store.html" class="stroke">
      <font>STORE</a>
    </font>
    <a id="music" href="music.html" class="stroke">
      <font>MUSIC</a>
    </font>
    <a id="connect" href="connect.html" class="stroke">
      <font>CONNECT</a>
    </font>
    <a id="submit" href="submit.html" class="stroke">
      <font>SUBMIT</a>
    </font>
  </div>
```

Comment: Your HTML is not correct. Besides that, you should use a list for this! http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_navbar.asp

Comment: What is the problem with the HTML @Timo002? I'll change it to list also, thank you for showing me the proper method.

Comment: `<font>` Tag is deprecated in HTML5

Comment: So I should just reformat it with the list format? Do you know if this would solve my links moving problem as well? I'm pretty new to this, so sorry for the amateur mistakes. @Wachtler

Comment: I kind of think that this question should be closed :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the demo : **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/g0j5kh6n/)**

1. Your html structure is wrong, you have not closed the `<a>` and `<font>` tag in the correct order.
2. `<font>`  tag is deprecated.
3. It is always best practice to create a menu using `<ul><li>` structure, by doing this way it avoids all the positioning which is unnecessary.

Please find the code below:

**HTML:**

```
<hr id="line1"/>

<div class="wrapper">
    <a href="gbwebsite.html"><img id="gblogo" src="images/GB.png" alt="good boy logo" width="128" height="128"/></a>
</div>      

<div id="font" class="wrapper">
  <ul>
    <li><a id="about" href="about.html" class="stroke">ABOUT</a></li>    
    <li><a id="news" href="news.html" class="stroke">NEWS</a></li>    
    <li><a id="store" href="store.html" class="stroke">STORE</a></li>    
    <li><a id="music" href="music.html" class="stroke">MUSIC</a></li>    
    <li><a id="connect" href="connect.html" class="stroke">CONNECT</a></li>    
    <li><a id="submit" href="submit.html" class="stroke">SUBMIT</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
ul li{list-style:none;}
.wrapper ul li{display:inline;}
.wrapper{text-align:center;}
.wrapper a{padding:5px;}
```

---

**Code snippet**

```css
  ul li{list-style:none;}
    .wrapper ul li{display:inline;}
    .wrapper{text-align:center;}
    .wrapper a{padding:5px;}
```

```html
<hr id="line1"/>
    
    <div class="wrapper">
        <a href="gbwebsite.html"><img id="gblogo" src="images/GB.png" alt="good boy logo" width="128" height="128"/></a>
    </div>      
    
    <div id="font" class="wrapper">
      <ul>
        <li><a id="about" href="about.html" class="stroke">ABOUT</a></li>    
        <li><a id="news" href="news.html" class="stroke">NEWS</a></li>    
        <li><a id="store" href="store.html" class="stroke">STORE</a></li>    
        <li><a id="music" href="music.html" class="stroke">MUSIC</a></li>    
        <li><a id="connect" href="connect.html" class="stroke">CONNECT</a></li>    
        <li><a id="submit" href="submit.html" class="stroke">SUBMIT</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I did do what you told me, but it ending making even more problems with my website. I think I'm just going to go and find some tutorials on how to properly position elements and etc. then just rebuild my website. It's been such a pain.

Comment: Provide the problem in a fiddle i can try helping you fix it and explain you how to proceed.

Comment: Here: jsfiddle.net/kj44Lcdr/ Thank you so much for the help ((: I really appreciate it.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kj44Lcdr/10/ is this what you are looking for?

Comment: try taking tutorials in codecademy.com or udemy.com on how to create websites. go to w3schools.com which is best for learning.

Comment: do not use position:relative or absolute to align elements always  that is so very wrong.check the fiddle and let me know whether that is what u wanted.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I wanted, but just the links above the Good Boy Slides. I've been looking for a place to learn this kind of stuff so thank you. I really want to get a grasp on CSS positioning. :p

Comment: How would I space out my elements though? They're really bunched up right now.

Comment: Padding or margin can be used for that.  Google them you will find out how to use it.

Answer (score 2):

Remove all the relative positioning stuff and just do this:

```
div {
    text-align: center;
}
```

To space them out use margin:

```
a {
    margin: 10px;
}
```

Also try searching around next time. I would check this out too http://learnlayout.com/